Is ECDH still secure if I embed the server public key?
I'm pretty new to the concept of key exchange.
Diffie-Hellman does not have authentication, so it makes no guarantees on who is the other party of the connection.
Both key pairs (client/server) need to be generated randomly in every connection for perfect forward secrecy to work. However, is this even necessary, for example on a mobile app that is always going to connect to the same server? Browsers using TLS cannot embed every public key ever for every domain, but a mobile app can.
Can I embed the public key of the server without compromising security, like this?
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(521);
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
KeyAgreement keyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH");
keyAgreement.init(privateKey);
PublicKey otherPublicKey = KeyTools.getPublicKey(KeyType.EC, "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
        "MIGbMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAjA4GGAAQB577J91d7YdINXVBJwGvI/mGReMX9\n" +
        "697rnO9gPwLWvsqX6NbKogYWkDSQTyqbd9Bztv9p5uhumPnK7/KIHpiFR2cAj8KG\n" +
        "2QjI4zIP8BHWsiJUfx479lUhX6lpslCQS/DejcWOan5ACmG0AGRhkJxSuynm+BDs\n" +
        "SFIVvvVRGC5LVcfzN4Y=\n" +
        "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n");
keyAgreement.doPhase(otherPublicKey, true);
SecretKey secretKey = keyAgreement.generateSecret("AES");
byte[] bufferKey = secretKey.getEncoded();


But the malicious actor still does not have access to the server's private key. The connection will inevitably fail in this case, right?

I guess I misunderstood your question, so I am deleting my earlier comment


Can I embed the public key of the server without compromising security, like this?

There are two potential issues, which might or might not be a problem (depending on what you're doing with the crypto).

There is no proof of liveness.  That is, an attacker can recover what a client sent you, repeat it exactly, and so give the server the exact same messages that the legitimate client gave you.

It lacks perfect forward secrecy.  That is, if the attacker gets the private key (say, by hacking the server, or getting a judge to issue a legal warrant), then he can decrypt previous exchanges and learn what was said.


Are either of these actually a problem for you?  Well, it depends on the data you're trying to protect.
For (1), you might not mind if the server gets a repeated message.  For example, if the message is "give me the contents of this web site page", you wouldn't care.  If the message is "transfer 1000 Simoleons from Alice's account to Bob's", you would care.  On the other hand, this can be addressed by the server generating some per-exchange randomness, which is stirred on the KDF on both sides - your example does not provide that.
For (2), you might not care if either the sensitivity of the message is limited (for example, the price of a specific stock - that's published 15 minutes later), or you don't care about privacy at all and are only concerned with integrity.  On the other hand, there are a host of reasons you might care - you would need to consider that.
If you do need PFS, the standard approach is to make the server key a signature key, and have the two sides do an ephemeral key exchange, which is authenticated by the signature.  If you're going to that extend, you might consider implementing either TLS or if that's a bit too heavyweight, EDHOC
